Recursive Definition of Var(φ) and Kon(φ) in Logical Formulas – Should I Use Parsing Trees?
I'm working on a problem in my logic course where I need to define two recursive functions:

$Var(\phi)$: Counts the number of variable occurrences in a logical formula $\phi$.
$Kon (\phi)$: Counts the number of connectives (excluding negations) in $\phi$.

For instance, if $\phi = \neg(p \land p) \rightarrow ((\neg r \lor q) \land q)$, then $Var(\phi) = 5$ and $Kon(\phi) = 4$.
In a previous conversation, I was taught how to count binary subexpressions and total subexpressions using parsing trees. I learned that I can construct a parsing tree to count subexpressions by treating each node as a subexpression, and that this approach could help with analyzing logical formulas structurally.
However, I'm not sure if I should apply this parsing tree approach to solve the first task here, or if there's another preferred method for defining these recursive functions.
Could anyone clarify whether the parsing tree method is relevant here, or suggest an alternative approach for defining $Var(\phi)$ and $Kon (\phi)$ recursively?
Thanks so much for any guidance!

@MauroALLEGRANZA I apologize for any confusion, but I’m unclear on where I should be directing my questions. To clarify, no one is being forced to answer anything. Personally, I learn best by engaging in discussions and asking questions. Not everyone has the luxury of a perfect instructor or a professor who covers every aspect required for assignments. Based on my previous posts, you can see that I show my attempts to solve the questions, but I feel more comfortable having someone else as a sounding board to tackle these problems. I have no sheet with answers.

Yes, parsing three will work. Base case=atom: one variable, no binary connective. Then negation of a formula: same number of variables and same number of binary connectives. And so on.

@Mauro Thanks, so for example, for $\phi=\neg(p \wedge p) \rightarrow((\neg r \vee q) \wedge q)$, I got this parsing tree, and it contains five nodes with variables, and four nodes with connectives if we ignore negation (which is specified by the assignment).

@MauroALLEGRANZA Ok, so I think, as an example, it would look similar to this:  (1) Var(e) = 0 ———— (2)  Var(a) = 1 ———— (3) Var(¬ϕ) = Var(ϕ) ———— (4) Var(ϕ*ψ) = Var(ϕ) + Var(ψ)
where e is the empty string, a is any variable, and * is any binary logical connective. Would it be wrong to exclude Var(e) = 0 in the definition?
Also, the definition for Kon should work similarly?

Yes, parsing three will work.
Base case=atom: one variable, no binary connective.
Then consider the negation of a formula: same number of variables and same number of binary connectives. And similar for binary connectives.
And yes, for formula $\varphi := ¬(p∧p) \to ((¬r∨q)∧q)$ you have $\text {Var}(\varphi)=5$ and $\text {Kon}(\varphi)=4$, because the assignment asks to count only binary ones.
Maybe the assignment asks not only to count them on the example, but to write the recursive functions for counting them in the general case, in which case:
Base case: $\varphi$ is an atomic formula: $\text {Var}(\varphi)=1$ and $\text {Kon}(\varphi)=0$.
Induction step: $\varphi$ is a formula with a negation sign: $\lnot \psi$, in which case: $\text {Var}(\varphi)=\text {Var}(\psi)$ and $\text {Kon}(\varphi)=\text {Kon}(\psi)$.
For a formula $\varphi$ with a binary connective: $\psi_1 \lor \psi_2$ we have: $\text {Var}(\varphi)=\text {Var}(\psi_1) + \text {Var}(\psi_1)$ and $\text {Kon}(\varphi)=\text {Kon}(\psi_1) + \text {Kon}(\psi_2)+1$.
